# Не срабатывает авторизация на StackOverflow

Tags: c#, http, post, request

Почему у меня не срабатывает авторизация на StackOverflow?

```
        public class Http
        {
            public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
            {
                byte[] response = null;
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
                }
                return response;
            }
        }
//........................
var response = Http.Post("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login", new NameValueCollection() {
    { "fkey", "Тут fkey лежит" },
    { "ssrc", "head" },
    { "email", "*******@gmail.com" },
    { "password", "********" },
});
```

Comment: А сервер что-то возвращает?

Comment: Да, просто не авторизированную страницу и всё

Comment: А почему не через API? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: @VladD не хочу так как не удобно, регать какой-то app надо, потом ещё новый и не понятный oauth (я знаю, что для большинства на этом форуме это ерунда, но только не для меня), чтобы просто получить html авторизированной страницы.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Через OAuth — это поддерживаемый путь, он будет работать. Через эмуляцию запроса из браузера может сработает, а может и нет, и имеет право в любой момент отвалиться.